# How do I show cell data as a value when referencing another cell that includes a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to show a cell value in a cell where it is being referenced to a cell that includes a simple formula. e.g.

In `D4` I want to reference `C4` (i.e. `=C4`) and show it as a value, where `C4` has a concatenate formula: `=concatenate("000",A4,"-",E4,"-",J4,"-",M4)`.

#### Explanation

I currently have a reference in D4 cell that is C4, which returns a value, in D4, of 0001-190716-AM-ABERD, for example. When I double click into D4 in order to copy the text as text, I simply get the formula i.e. =C4. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way that I can put a formula into D4 that not only returns the value 0001-190716-AM-ABERD, but returns it as text - so when I double click into the cell the text shows and not the formula?

Comment: I don't understand "show it as a value" means. If the result of formula is 000-222-111, then this is what will be seen in both C4 and D4, provided you have `=C4` in the D4 cell.

Comment: I currently have a reference in D4 cell that is =C4, which returns a value, in D4, of 0001-190716-AM-ABERD, for example. When I double click into D4 in order to copy the text as text, I simply get the formula i.e. =C4. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way that I can put a formula into D4 that not only returns the value 0001-190716-AM-ABERD, but returns it as text - so when I double click into the cell the text shows and not the formula?

Comment: This can't be done. Just don't double click. Click once to select a cell, and copy.

Comment: I owndered if that was the case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If a user double-clicks in a cell, what they see is their **input** into that cell. In the situation described, that input will be a formula, for example `=C4`, not the output of that formula such as "0001-190716-AM-ABERD".

To copy the **output** of a formula, select the cell by clicking on it once, then copy. When pasting the result in another place in the spreadsheet, you have two options:

- ordinary paste Ctrl-V will copy the formula, adjusting its cell references
- value-only paste Ctrl-Shift-V will copy only the output of the formula, as plain text.